# Generating WSDL from WCF Service on Build

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, svc

**The Info**
File: C:\MyObjectService.svc

**The Question**
I want to be able to generate a MyObjectService.wsdl file from "C:\MyObjectService.svc"
on build

**Extra info**
My service is running under `"http://localhost:1234/MyObjectService/"`

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:1234/MyObjectService/?wsdl`

Comment: `wsdl.exe` should help you - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I want to generate it on build

Comment: `wsdl.exe` should not be used any loger. Use `svcutil.exe` instead.

Comment: You generally do not want to generate the WSDL on build, only on request. If you need the WSDL as a static file, then you can use `svcutil.exe` during your build.

Comment: thx for the info I will look into the svcutil!